# Yii2 exempt controller actions from http bearer auth

Tags: php, yii2

I have setup my yii2 restful controller but i would like to exempt an action login from httpbearer auth method since no access token is sent during login

This is the way i have setup

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
 {

  public function behaviors()
    {
    $behaviors = parent::behaviors();

    $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
        'class' => CompositeAuth::className(),
        'authMethods' => [
            HttpBasicAuth::className(),
            HttpBearerAuth::className(),
            QueryParamAuth::className(),
        ],
    ];
     return $behaviors;

   }


   public function actionLogin(){
   //login logic
  }
```

what do i need to add to the `$behaviours['authenticator']` to exempt Login action from it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is ActionFilter you can add in the behavior's config:

```
'except' => ['login']
```

Comment: wrks like charm